# Как исправить ошибку events.js:154 при запуске gulp-autoprefixer?

Tags: gulp

Нашел на просторах интернета похожую ошибку по ссылке

https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-autoprefixer/issues/81

По сути ошибка следующего характера
- при запуске gulp-autoprefixer выдает ошибку

```
    events.js:154
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
TypeError: this is not a typed array.
    at Function.from (native)
```

Версия установленного Node.js 5.7.0
Автопрефиксер подключаю к .css файлам.

Подскажите пожалуйста, какие еще могут быть варианты решения, в чем еще может быть причина данной ошибки?

Comment: Добавьте код гулпфайла

Comment: <code>
events.js:154
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
TypeError: this is not a typed array.
    at Function.from (native)
    at Z:\tasks\testgulp\markup\build\node_modules\gulp-autoprefixer\index.js:25:27
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:406:9)
</code>